# How to reliably subclass UITableViewCell for grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, subclass

When writing a customized subclass of `UITableViewCell`, I find that the results work well for the rectangular cells of a plain-styled `UITableView`, but do not work at all for the rounded cells in a grouped-styled table.

Is there a way to reliably subclass `UITableViewCell` to draw cells which work for grouped-style tables? (Without using Interface Builder.)

Answer (score 9):

Could the answer be as simple as first calling `[super layoutSubviews]` inside your `UITableViewCell` subclass’s `layoutSubviews` method?

Here is my code.

First I create the `UITextField` and add it to the `contentView` in the `initWithStyle:` method:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        inputField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [self.contentView addSubview:inputField];
        inputField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        [inputField release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then in layoutSubviews, I’ve got this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    inputField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 20);
}
```

With that code, the text field is 5px from the left of the screen, which is, of course, 5px to the left of the table cell when it’s in grouped mode. In other words, OUTSIDE of the table view cell. No good.

Use this code and the `inputField` is placed 5px to the right of the cell, like I want it to be:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews]; // the magic line
    inputField.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 100, 20);
}
```

I could have totally misunderstood the problem you were having, though!

Erik

Comment: How could I miss that?!! Thank you so much for the magic line!

Answer (score 8):

I used to have lots of problems with `UITableViewCell` subclasses, but then I just stopped subclassing.
Adding subviews to the `contentView` property of a `UITableViewCell` seems to accomplish the same thing in any instance that I've run across, so I just do that inside my `UITableViewController`.

Here's an example that has a title and value:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{    
    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"AccountDetailsCell";
    UILabel* mainLabel = nil;
    UILabel* valueLabel = nil;
    const CGFloat kAccountDetailFontSize = 14.0;

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if ( cell == nil ) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        mainLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 10.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0 )] autorelease];
        mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
        mainLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: kAccountDetailFontSize];
        mainLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        mainLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: mainLabel];

        valueLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake( 150.0, 0.0, 150.0, 44.0 )] autorelease];
        valueLabel.tag = VALUELABEL_TAG;
        valueLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: kAccountDetailFontSize];
        valueLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
        valueLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
        valueLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        valueLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview: valueLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        mainLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: MAINLABEL_TAG];
        valueLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag: VALUELABEL_TAG];
    }

    mainLabel.text = (NSString*)kCellTitles[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    valueLabel.text = [self tableView: tableView valueLabelTextForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm finding that this approach isn't sufficient for my needs. I have a cell which has a multi-line title and multi-line description and autoresizes itself based on the text contained in the two labels. I'm sizing things in -(void)layoutSubviews and remembering to call [super layoutSubviews] first, but it seems to me that self.contentView is still not resizing until after this call, and thus sometimes my cells end up the wrong height.

Comment: Such method good,but if you want to use QuartzCore things like shadow for labels, then scrolling will be slow, and you have to draw cell yourself.

Comment: I've since been much happier with subclasses as many of the problems I did have were corrected in more recent SDKs. My current method involves a subclass with a `configureWithDataObject: (id)dataObject` method that I then subclass for my custom cells. My view controller automatically picks the correct cell subclass and calls `configureWithDataObject:`. Makes development fast and easy (although it is technically less efficient than doing it all in static code).

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed this problem as well. My workaround has been to just make my table cells smaller (300 width instead of 320). It's not a great solution, but it works well.

I don't believe you can get rid of the table view insets on an individual basis when in "grouped" mode. I could be wrong though!

Answer (score -1):

What problem are you having?  In drawRect you are given a rect, and know your total size - just conform to that space.  If you are using layoutSubviews, same thing.

Comment: The problem is UITableView in grouped mode cuts off parts of the cells (the sides, to reveal the background and it also rounds the corners of the top and bottom cells of a section).

Comment: After some further tests, you're right that the table view cells do not get passed in the correct size in drawRect.  An alternate approach is to set a custom backgroundView for a standard UITableViewCell, and do all your drawing there.  You get a cell the right width but you have to draw the rounded top and bottom corners correctly yourself.